# External Native Build Issues Android Studio NDK Sample HelloJni (Build Failed)

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-ndk

> Error: executing external native build for cmake C:\Users\PC1\Desktop\ndkdata\GDNdkText\app\CMakeLists.txt

#### Error While Building:

[image: Error Image]

I have installed NDK, CMake, LLDP as mentioned [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#download-ndk). Do I need to install any other tool or need to set any environment variables?

Answer (score 12):

open Terminal and run this command:

```
gradlew build --stacktrace
```

[image]

Comment: Its `gradlew build --stacktrace`

Answer (score 6):

If you run under Linux you need to install Ninja. 
sudo apt install ninja-build

Tested today.

Answer (score 5):

you have to install ninja using homebrew

```
brew install ninja
```

Comment: It works on MacOs. Homebrew may ask to change the ownership of some directories, in my case I used the command `sudo chown -R user_name /usr/local/lib/pkgconfig`, where `user_name` is the name of the current user. And after that the command `brew install ninja` did the trick.

Answer (score 2):

You also need to install `ncurses5` (for arch-linux its AUR package - `ncurses5-compat-libs`), since NDK support on Android Studio 2.2 doesn't use ncurses6 which might be installed on your system.

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem with examining log files.

```
./app/.cxx/cmake/commonDebug/x86/android_gradle_generate_cmake_ninja_json_x86.stderr.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is the wrong location of CMakelist.txt file.

Try to move CMakelist.txt file from your app root directory to app/src/main/cpp/CMakelist.txt directory and then update the location from gradle file also like this:

```
externalNativeBuild {
    cmake {
        path "src/main/cpp/CMakeLists.txt"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your project without including any C++ files
make sure that you did not check the box that say include C++ 
in the beginning of new project

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue when importing a co-workers workspace.  We were getting external native build errors.  And it seemed like the IDE was ignoring a lot of the CMake commands.

It turns out the issue was that I didn't have Ninja installed as suggest in ariel's post above.  I discovered this by running `gradlew build --stacktrace` and found a line complaining about not having Ninja installed.  Note: we are developing in a linux environment.

Ninja is a build system that focuses on speed, and is used to replace `make` in systems with a large number of input files.  [Ninja Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ninja_(build_system))

Once I installed ninja, everything build perfectly!